# R ggplot: line around legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to use ggplot2 for my data plotting.

For purely superficial reasons I would like to have a line around my legend so as to better distinguish it from the plot (i.e. a black outline around the legend box). I could not find an answer to this question on any forum, but maybe you have a tip?

```
library(ggplot2)

Res = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 500)
Res[,1] = 1:500
Res[,2] = sin((2*pi)/100*Res[,1])
Res[,3] = cos((2*pi)/100*Res[,1])
Res = as.data.frame(Res)
colnames(Res) = c("X", "Y1", "Y2")

ggplot(Res, aes(X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Y1, colour = "1"), size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Y2, colour = "2"), size = 2) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Y's", labels = c(" sine", " cosine")) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.9, 0.7))
```

Comment: The Legend square box, A border?

Comment: Adding `legend.background = element_rect(fill = "grey", colour = "black")` in `theme(...)` should distinguish legend by adding black border around legend

Comment: I was more thinking of an outline around the legend box.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will give an outline around legend

```
library(ggplot2)

Res = matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 500)
Res[,1] = 1:500
Res[,2] = sin((2*pi)/100*Res[,1])
Res[,3] = cos((2*pi)/100*Res[,1])
Res = as.data.frame(Res)
colnames(Res) = c("X", "Y1", "Y2")

ggplot(Res, aes(X)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Y1, colour = "1"), size = 2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Y2, colour = "2"), size = 2) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Y's", labels = c(" sine", " cosine")) +
  theme(legend.position=c(0.9, 0.7)) +  
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(colour = 'black', fill = 'white', linetype='solid'))
```

You can read more about legend settings here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/wiki/Legend-Attributes

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much!